# Как изменить цвет текста WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi

По умолчанию в текстовое поле вводиться черный цвет, какие функций существуют, чтобы например после нажатия кнопки вводился синий цвет??
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd144821(v=vs.85).aspx глядите здесь, SetTextColor видимо вам и хочется.

Comment: А как привязать нужный текстбокс к этой функции ?